# How can I add widget to the Core group in ImpressPages CMS

Tags: impresspages

Thank you for the great and flexible CMS. Let's explore the limits of the flexibility...

My custom widgets are appear in the "Other" group on the toolbar. Is there any way to add it to the "Core" group?

I tried to experiment with Ip/Internal/Content/Widget, but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you mean to post this somewhere else, or were you sent here by some resource?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I just want to use it in my work. It's my personal question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by catching a filter "ipAdminWidgets"

https://www.impresspages.org/docs/filter-list